# compiling OpenHEVC with Emscripten

Tags: emscripten

I'm trying to compile OpenHEVC with Emscripten, but I can't, I'm facing a lot of errors, has anyone already compiled it?

the complation commands that I could find on the internet are the following:

mkdir build
cd build
emcmake cmake ..
emmake make